# Oauth Error while extending Magento Rest API

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, extensions, api, oauth

I am working with Magento Rest API for the first time, i went through the tutorials of Rest API on `http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest` and tried one example to fetch product through API:

```
$callbackUrl = "http://localhost/wineshop/products.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://localhost/wineshop/oauth/initiate?     oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://localhost/wineshop/admin/oauth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://localhost/wineshop/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://localhost/wineshop/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 'u48p1x9gzrg7r82c94woa5z7g805uw0i';
$consumerSecret = '96ydrk8s89xxath8h5z71vcl5abfq0zg';

session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
$_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
$authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
$oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret,  OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
$oauthClient->enableDebug();
```

I've also installed the latest version of OAUTH and it also shows in my WampServer PHP Extensions but it doesn't show in `phpinfo()`. I coped the `php_oauth.dll` file into `..\www\bin\php\ext` and i also edited `php.ini` and entered `extension=php_oauth.dll` but on running the `products.php` it shows me the

```
Fatal error: Class 'OAuth' not found in P:\wamp\www\products.php on line 19
```

And i also want to know that how to request for the token i've got `key` and `secret` after entering new consumer in Magento Admin Panel. But i don't know how to get `Access Token` & `Access Token Secret` that we enter in `RESTClient`

Please Help, Thanks in advance

Comment: This appears to be an issue loading the library. WAMP can be a... fickle thing. Are you use you edited the correct php.ini? If it doesn't show in your phpinfo something is wrong, either your DLL is in the wrong place, or the php.ini is the wrong one.

Comment: I edited the php.ini in **wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3** and copied the DLL in **wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext**

Comment: Just asking to be sure, but did you restart apache after modifying your `php.ini` file?

Comment: Yes i did, i restarted my WAMP Server after it.

Comment: Instead of `new OAuth(...`, try using `new \OAuth(...` (add a backslash before the class name)

Answer (score 1):

I can partially answer your question.

`Access Token` and `Access Token secret` are provided by the authentication server upon request and they validate the further requests.

Just a matter of chance, you can check if `oAuth` works for you by following [this](http://www.aschroder.com/2012/04/introduction-to-the-magento-rest-apis-with-oauth-in-version-1-7/) link

Comment: Yes i followed all the steps on given link but the thing is i'm having this **oAuth** error so i can't go ahead and without running this file i will not be able to get Access Token or Access Token Secret.

Comment: Can you tell the exact error? In case I might know the solution....